# How to allow missing ExpressionAttributeValues with FilterExpression in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to cater for a optional ExpressionAttributeValue so as not to break your FilterExpression i.e.

a filter expression:

```
FilterExpression: 'country = :country and age = :age'
```

Is there syntax to add to the expression to allow :country to be optional and ignored if so.

Equivalent in SQL

```
where (country = @country OR @country is null)
```

Right now I am doing:
(country = :country or :country = :none)

and :none is 'none'

Comment: Would you like to check the existence of the attribute 'country' or whether the country value has value null?

Comment: If the attribute is being passed in to use as filter criteria

Comment: There is no option. You need to form the FilterExpression conditionally i.e. @country is not null, then include the country in the filter expression. Otherwise don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FilterExpression `age = :age AND country IN :country, :null` and ExpressionAttributeValues `{":age":20, ":country":"Japan", ":null":none}`?